# What are the available fields types in Odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am looking for a simple list like this:

- fields.Char: Text field. It holds X number of characters
- fields.Boolean: True or False
- etc

I assumed I will get an easy answer on Google but for some reason I have not found a document that lists them all for Odoo 10. Am I not searching correctly?

Comment: Please refer this link it's useful for you : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/howtos/backend.html#model-fields

Comment: @Bhoomi Patel: Thanks. I did review that link. It is an extremely valuable tutorial to get you going with the basics of Odoo.  But per what I can tell it does not give a complete list of Model Fields. For example, the section you quoted does not mention "float" or "integer". (Float is explained as a note in the "Views" section). I was looking for a quick references, where one can see the whole set at a glace.

Answer (score 2):

You could find all the available Odoo fields at:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/fields.py

Answer (score 2):

Field types in odoo 10

1 - boolean: A boolean (true, false)

2 - integer: An integer.

3 - float: A floating point number.

4 - char: A string of limited length.

5 - text: A text field with no limit in length.

6 - date: A date.

7 - datetime: Allows to store a date and the time of day in the same field.

8 - binary: A binary chain (For image etc.)

9 - selection: A field which allows the user to make a selection between various predefined values.

Relational Types:

10 - one2one: A one2one field expresses a one:to:one relation between two objects

11 - many2one: Associates this object to a parent object via this Field

12 - one2many: For many Records.

13 - many2many

14 - related : for the relation purpose for ex. you want country related to city then it will use.

15 - Functional Fields : A functional field is a field whose value is calculated by a function

Answer (score 1):

There are some documentations around the net but the best choice would be to look into the code itself. Axel Mendoza already answered with this.

But another good choice is the [official developer documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#fields). If you need it for another version, just change it in the upper right corner.